# What's the difference between dropping and ignoring a TCP packet?

Tags: tcp

I can read in an article (about packet checking sequence) that if the ACK number is invalid, we drop the TCP packet.
If it is valid, we then do a 0-payload-check, if the payload's size is 0, we ignore the packet.

Is there a difference?

Comment: Any answer must first define in what regard to measure the "difference".

Answer (score 2):

Basically none.  DROP will increment the drop counter; ignore doesn't.